# Textarea field, border 2px on focus, moves other HTML elements

Tags: css, html, styles, textarea

The problem: 
I've created a simple test page (below) to demonstrate what the problem is. 
When you set CSS on textarea field with **border = 2px**, the textarea will resize itself 
and hence all fields/content below textarea will move down.

This only applies to textarea and select fields while input field doesn't act this way.

I've tested this in IE, Opera and FF and none of them produce the same behavior, 
they all work like they should while Chrome moves all elements below them.

Anyone knows a fix that will prevent this with CSS?

The example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<style language="text/css"> 
textarea:focus { 
        border: 2px solid #000000; 
} 
textarea { 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 100px; 
        resize: none; 
        outline: none; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 

<form> 
<textarea name="test" cols="0" rows="0"></textarea> 
<br /> 
This text and button will move a few pixels down when you click in textarea field. 
<br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is happening because you are giving border on `hover`. The border should already be there as transparent color and on `hover` or `focus` just give border-color.

```
textarea:focus { 
        border-color:#000000; 
} 
textarea { 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 100px; 
        resize: none; 
        outline: none;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This fixed all my problems

Answer (score 0):

Use css **box-sizing: border-box;** property in your textarea css. see example :

```
textarea { 
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. Actually Chrome adds the border excluding from width and height.

You can check this by using "box-sizing" property.

The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.
Happy Coding!